# Promise not returning correct result values to variables in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise

The console log result is as follows:

```
(3) [Promise, Promise, Promise]
0: Promise
[[Prototype]]: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: "urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.folder:co.uqbu12FFQZO6y7GxUs7cKA"
1: Promise
[[Prototype]]: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: "urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.folder:co.uqbu12FFQZO6y7GxUs7cKA"
2: Promise
[[Prototype]]: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: "urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.folder:co.uqbu12FFQZO6y7GxUs7cKA"
```

I am trying the following to extract the data [[PromiseResult]] form the array,
with the following code:

```
   const final_results = [];
        for (const vals in final_vals) {
          // const temp = Promise.all(vals).then(function (values) {
          //   final_results.push(values.result);
          // });

          const temp = Object.values(vals);
          final_results.push(temp);
        }
        console.log(final_results);
```

I am trying to get the output with the results as an Array with the following values:

["urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.folder:co.uqbu12FFQZO6y7GxUs7cKA","urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.folder:co.uqbu12FFQZO6y7GxUs7cKA","urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.folder:co.uqbu12FFQZO6y7GxUs7cKA"]

Comment: Could you add the entire function.

Comment: looks like you need to `await` the promise.all inside the for loop. that will prevent your log from running until the arrays of arrays of promises resolve